# How to get server event notification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm just getting into sql-server, so forgive me if this is a basic question. I'm building an application using .NET 4.0 and VS 2010 and ms-server2008.

For my application I need to detect the server response, suppose: in db-server I need to detect which table insert/update/delete records, and which is the affected record is?

Is there any mechanism or technique to detect the server response.

If have any questions please ask.

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11422/implementing-pub-sub-initiated-from-the-database/11431#11431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are

- to use stored procedures for data access and write log of changes,
- or to use triggers on specified tables to write log of changes

and after it you have periodically poll the log tables to reflect to the tables changes

See related answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998545/notifications-from-sqlserver-to-java/8998579#8998579

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895595/sql-server-track-table-inserts/8895683#8895683

Comment: Oleg Dok thanks for reply.can u plz show me some sample or example,i want to know this process name is?

Comment: Updated answer.